# Not able to play base64 string created using jsmidi

Tags: midi

I am creating base64 string for sequence of notes using jsmidi

https://github.com/sergi/jsmidi

Here is my string:

```
'data:audio/mid;base64,TVRoZAAAAAYAAAABAIBNVHJrAAAAhAGRPH88gTx
/AJE+fzyBPn8AkUB/PIFAfwCRQn88gUJ/AJFDfzyBQ38AkUV/PIFFfwCRR388gUd
/AJFIfzyBSH8AkUh/PIFIfwCRR388gUd/AJFFfzyBRX8AkUN/PIFDfwCRQn88gUJ
/AJFAfzyBQH8AkT5/PIE+fwCRPH88gTx/AP8vAA=='
```

And trying to play it using MIDI.js player, below is my code

```
MIDI.Player.loadFile(string);
MIDI.Player.start();
```

It does not play the string, even no error or warning, what could be an issue? Please guide.